# Question about fundamental frequencies

Tags: waves, frequency, string, wavelength, harmonics

For a string fixed at both ends, with a fundamental frequency of 440Hz, can there be a harmonic when a wave of frequency 220Hz is sent across the string? my book says no, but I disagree; can't standing waves and hence harmonics exist when its 1/2 a wavelength?

Comment: 220 Hz is not half the wavelength but twice the wavelength of the fundamental mode. Half the wavelength would be 880 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

The 220Hz wave requires double the wavelength of the fundamental if the velocity is fixed,  from $v=f\lambda$, however all harmonics have a wavelength equal to or smaller than the fundamental.

[image]

from [here](https://www.earmaster.com/music-theory-online/ch03/chapter-3-2.html)

Comment: "however all harmonics have a wavelength equal to or smaller than the fundamental." but the first harmonic in the diagram (assuming the fundamental wavelength is the distance from both fixed ends) has 2x a wavelength of the fundamental wavelength..

Comment: @seb aye hi, the term 'fundamental wavelength' is the distance for a full wave of the fundamental mode, i.e imagine we extended the red line of the top diagram until it looked like a complete wave.  It would then look like the blue one of the second diagram, but would have a length twice the distance between the lines. That is, the wavelength of the fundamental is twice the distance between the lines.